# how to setup fedex shipping method for multiple shipping addresses in woocommerc?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, fedex

I am developing a ecommerce site using **WooCommerce 2.1.6** and using **Shipping Multiple Addresses** extension to ship products to multiple addresses and also using **WooCommerce Fedex Shipping Pro** extension to ship product with fedex shipping method

But when i am using single shipping address to ship products, the fedex shipping options are showing properly, but when i assign multiple products to multiple shipping addresses, the fedex shipping method options are not showing in the list, i don't understand the issue

please help me to solve the issue or suggest any other woocommerce fedex extensions that ship products to multiple addresses.

Thank you very much.

Comment: It might be because Fedex Shipping Pro doesn't support such option. I would highly recommend emailing the author of the plugin to check with them directly whether this is possible currently or maybe in the near future.

Answer (score 0):

I am Strongly suggesting you WooForce [Fedex](https://www.xadapter.com/product/woocommerce-fedex-shipping-plugin-with-print-label/) Plugin. Once you purchased the premium version, They will provide you some snippet to do this.

Usually, they are very customer friendly and respond very quickly. So that you can expect help from their side to config properly.